# eching md5 hashtag values

Tags: php, mysql

I have user passwords in my database, which were inputted in md5 hashtag format.  Now when I try to echo a user's password, the value that is outputed is different from the md5 hashtag value in the database.
e.g: password in database is 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
password echo'd out below is dc0ae7e1387be9b795f5d6299e383759

```
$select=queryMysql("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='$user'"); 
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($select);
$password=$fetch['password'];

echo $password;
```

I am creating a password change form (i.e., a form where the user can change password) and need the user to verify that they know their current password before the create a new one.

This is how the password was created, when the user signed up:

```
if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user = trim(sanitizeString($_POST['user']));
    $pass = trim(sanitizeString($_POST['pass']));
    $pass_hash = md5(sanitizeString($_POST['pass']));

    $mydomain = trim(substr($user, strrpos($user, '@') + 1));
    if ($user == "" || $pass == "" )
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br /><br />";
    else
    {
        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM members
              WHERE user='$user'")))
            $error = "That username already exists<br /><br />";
        else
          {
            queryMysql("INSERT INTO members VALUES('$user', '$pass_hash', '$mydomain')");
            die("<h4>Account created</h4>Please log in.<br /><br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: md5 *hashtag* format?

Comment: if the value in the DB isn't what php gave you from the database, you searched for the wrong user. simple as that. md5 is not the problem unless there is a salt involved that you don't know about. If you want a sufficient answer, provide the code that creats the password,

Comment: _"I am creating a password change form"_ instead of displaying the password to user, just take his input and match with the password. like `md5($user_Input)`

Comment: @jogesh_pi - seems like that is what he is doing, he doesn't say anything about returning plain text passwords...

Comment: @Bryan I guess according to his question's title, _"Now when I try to echo a user's password"_ Means he don't know much about `md5()` function. Might be OP trying to match his password like `password=password` not in `md5()`!

Comment: Ok, i just added the code that created the password.  This password was created upon user signup.

Comment: @user3388726 then what you want from us? What you are trying to do? We need more clarification

Comment: yeah, i don't see any salts or anything like that, make sure $user is say same thing you're checking with in the db as in the script.